# Invalid or unexpected token in JS function

Tags: javascript, token

here's my code so far, I need to create a slideshow using the buttons - so if I click btn1 => pic1 appears, etc.
I succeed to create the code that only appends the new pictures by clicks, but that's not exactly  what I need. I can use only JavaScript, no jQuery.

My code is below, I will be happy receive any help. Thanks!
Also it doesn't render anything in jsfiddle or maybe that's my awful internet.

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.id = "mainDiv";
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

var divOne = document.createElement("div");
divOne.id = "one";
newDiv.appendChild(divOne);

var divTwo = document.createElement("div");
divTwo.id = "two";
newDiv.appendChild(divTwo);

var divThree = document.createElement("div");
divThree.id = "three";
newDiv.appendChild(divThree);


var btn1 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn1.textContent = "1";
btn1.id = "but1";
newDiv.appendChild(btn1);

document.getElementById("but1").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("one").className = "firstImg";
}​;

var btn2 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn2.textContent = "2";
btn2.id = "but2";
newDiv.appendChild(btn2);

document.getElementById("but2").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("two").className = "secondImg";
};

var btn3 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn3.textContent = "3";
btn3.id = "but3";
newDiv.appendChild(btn3);

document.getElementById("but3").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("three").className = "thirdImg";
}​;
```

Comment: After finding out the error is what it says it is, I don't mind if you delete the question :-)

Answer (score 2):

Delete and retype the lines that are reported to have illegal characters. The post contains two zero width space characters, Unicode U+200b, which are generating console errors for invalid characters in lines 25 and 43. After removal the code starts to work (it creates buttons on the page at least).

How they got there is hard to say - usually it's fat fingered typing that does it for me, but who knows.